# Counting non repeating integers

Tags: java

I need help with a coding question. I would like some tips on finding the answer but not the answer itself.

Sample input looks like this 3112.

Sample output is 2 because the integers doesn't repeat.

here's the code

```
public static int lonelyInteger(int[] arr)
{

    need to code this 

}


public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    final String fileName = System.getenv("OUTPUT_PATH");
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileName));
    int res;

    int _arr_size = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
    int[] _arr = new int[_arr_size];
    int _arr_item;
    for(int _arr_i = 0; _arr_i < _arr_size; _arr_i++)
    {
        _arr_item = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
        _arr[_arr_i] = _arr_item;
    }

    res = loneyInteger(_arr);
    bw.write(String.valueOf(res));
    bw.newLine();

    bw.close();
}
```

Comment: Can you give more sample test cases? The one you gave doesn't make sense to me. I'm not sure how you got 2.

Comment: @4castle There are two different integers that do not repeat themselves (3 and 2).

Comment: Just an overview: Iterate thru each digit. For each digit see if it occurs again within the number. If it does not, then add one to an index counter.

Comment: The 3 doesn't repeat, why don't you check for that?    As for hints, I'd iterate down the string by character, starting with the first character, and checking whether each successive character matched the previous one.   Set a boolean whether there was a previous match, if not, you've got a "lonely" integer.

Comment: @DanielWiddis Why turn the already `int` into a `String`? Imagine running it for `1e9` numbers. The run time would increase dramatically.

Comment: What would be the output of `[1, 2, 1, 2]`? Would it be `4` or `0`?

Comment: @4castle From what I understand, he's asking for the total number of digits that are unique in the number. So the result of that would be `0`.

Comment: @Dando18 I'm not so sure. In my mind there's a difference between looking for "repeating" numbers and looking for "duplicate" numbers.

Comment: @Dando18 The question asked for hints, not the answer.   If you're iterating over digits you need to either turn it into a string to use the characters or do a bunch of division by 10 to get the digits.   The question complicates things by asking for hints and not the answer... the idea was to get OP thinking along that iterative path, not to necessarily solve it.

Comment: @DanielWiddis my apologies

Answer (score 0):

Write a loop that iterates from the start to the end of `arr`, and check the element in front and behind at each index for it it contains a different value. If the value is different from the previous and next elements, add one to the counter. Make sure to do a check that the index in front or behind aren't equal to `-1` or `arr.length` before accessing those indexes.

Spoiler:

> `int count = 0;
>  for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
>      if (i-1 >= 0 && arr[i] == arr[i-1] ||
>          i+1 < arr.length && arr[i] == arr[i+1])
>          continue;
>      else
>          count++;
>  return count;`

Answer (score 0):

You can make a counter for the integers that repeated themselves while you read them .

For example :

```
for(int _arr_i = 0; _arr_i < _arr_size; _arr_i++)
{
   _arr_item = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
   if (itemNotInList(_arr_item))
      repeatedItemsCounter++;
}
unrepeadedItems = allItems - repeatedItemsCounter
```